# Can you add more than one partition in one "ALTER TABLE" command?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm using Amazon Athena to query through some log files stored in an S3 bucket, and am using partitions to section off days of the year for the files I need to query. I was wondering -- since I have a large batch of days to add to my table, could I do it all in one `ALTER TABLE` command, or do I need to have as many `ALTER TABLE` commands as the number of partitions I would like to create?

This is an example of the command I am using at the moment:

```
ALTER TABLE
  logfiles
ADD PARTITION
  (day='20170525')
location 's3://log-bucket/20170525/';
```

If I do have to use one `ALTER TABLE` command per partition, is there a way to create a range of days, and then have Athena loop through it to create the partitions, instead of me manually copy/pasting out this command 100+ times?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that you *can* add many partitions to one `ALTER TABLE` command, per the Athena documentation found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html or go do the athena root and search for add partition.

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD
  PARTITION (dt = '2016-05-14', country = 'IN') LOCATION 's3://mystorage/path/to/INDIA_14_May_2016'
  PARTITION (dt = '2016-05-15', country = 'IN') LOCATION 's3://mystorage/path/to/INDIA_15_May_2016';
```